# Not getting expected error message from nested json schema validation

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, json-schema-validator

Trying to validate the json in azure logic app using json schema validation.

This is my sample json:

```
{
    "address": [
        {
            "contact": {
                "firstName": "myFirstName",
                "lastName": "myLastName"
            },
            "type": "bill"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my schema:

```
{
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "address": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "const": "bill"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "address": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "properties": {
                        "contact": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "required": [
                                "firstName"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't pass firstName attribute in input json, the validation is getting failed which is expected, but the error message I am getting is not correct. It does not show which attribute is missing. Like in this example I am expecting the message should tell the firstName attribute is missing.

This is output of above validation:

```
"outputs": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "JSON does not match schema from 'then'.",
                    "lineNumber": 0,
                    "linePosition": 0,
                    "path": "",
                    "schemaId": "#/then",
                    "errorType": "then",
                    "childErrors": []
                }
            ]
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you want us to do? It is what it is.

Comment: @Skin, if I use condition schema validation i.e. if-then-else like above,  I am not getting proper error message, in message the required attribute name is not coming up. 
What change I need to do in schema so that I will get the expected error message?

Comment: it will give this https://i.imgur.com/3n6mq8r.png message if you use conditional validation.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, I have taken a http trigger and then taken parse json step and gave the below schema in it.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "address": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "contact": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "firstName": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "message": {
                                    "required": "name is required"
                                },
                                "required": true
                            },
                            "lastName": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "contact",
                    "type"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Now in response action:

```
outputs('Parse_JSON')['errors'][0]['message']
```

[image]

After i have kept **runAfter Failed** to get the message and then you can use any parallel action also.

**Output:**

[image]

Output In logic app:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code view:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@triggerBody()",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "address": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "contact": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "firstName": {
                                                    "message": {
                                                        "required": "name is required"
                                                    },
                                                    "required": true,
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "lastName": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "contact",
                                        "type"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Response": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": "@outputs('Parse_JSON')['errors'][0]['message']",
                    "statusCode": 200
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Failed"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Response"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

You can do only this and i do agree with @skin about this.

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja for you response,  but you have not used conditional validation like I mentioned in my schema. We are getting proper error messages when we don't have conditional validation but it is not working with conditional (if-then-else) validation

Comment: In conditional validation you will get same as you have got as @skin mentioned. But why to use it, you  can use normal validation right? JSON does not match schema from 'then this message only you will get for that

Comment: I have required where I need to use conditional validation, that can not achieved through normal validation.

Comment: then you will get https://i.imgur.com/3n6mq8r.png this as message

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the workaround and that is using `oneOf`.

Modified schema:

```
{
    "if": {
        "properties": {
            "address": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "const": "bill"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "properties": {
                    "address": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "contact": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "required": [
                                        "firstName"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the schema validation output for failed scenario.

```
[
    {
        "message": "JSON does not match schema from 'then'.",
        "lineNumber": 0,
        "linePosition": 0,
        "path": "",
        "schemaId": "#/then",
        "errorType": "then",
        "childErrors": [
            {
                "message": "JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'.",
                "lineNumber": 0,
                "linePosition": 0,
                "path": "",
                "schemaId": "#/then",
                "errorType": "oneOf",
                "childErrors": [
                    {
                        "message": "Required properties are missing from object: firstName.",
                        "lineNumber": 0,
                        "linePosition": 0,
                        "path": "address[0].contact",
                        "value": [
                            "firstName"
                        ],
                        "schemaId": "#/then/oneOf/0/properties/address/items/properties/contact",
                        "errorType": "required",
                        "childErrors": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

firstName missing attribute is coming up in error response for conditional schema validation