# Azure Logic Apps: How to be notified if a logic app action connection breaks or fails

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, kql, azure-diagnostics

I want to build a logic app that tells me when any of the logic apps in my environment fail or a connection is broken. (both manual triggers of logic apps and automated)

The closest KQL i've found to achieve this is:

```
SentinelHealth 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where SentinelResourceType == "Automation rule"
| mv-expand TriggeredPlaybooks = ExtendedProperties.TriggeredPlaybooks
| extend runId = tostring(TriggeredPlaybooks.RunId)
| join (AzureDiagnostics 
    | where OperationName == "Microsoft.Logic/workflows/workflowRunCompleted"
    | extend IncidentNumber = toint(extract(@"[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-[a-f0-9]{12}\_(\d+)", 1, correlation_clientTrackingId_s))
    | project
        IncidentNumber,
        resource_runId_s,
        playbookName = resource_workflowName_s,
        playbookRunStatus = status_s)
    on $left.runId == $right.resource_runId_s
| project
    RecordId,
    TimeGenerated,
    AutomationRuleName= SentinelResourceName,
    AutomationRuleStatus = Status,
    Description,
    workflowRunId = runId,
    playbookName,
    playbookRunStatus,
    IncidentNumber
```

[KQL source](https://github.com/ep3p/Sentinel_KQL/blob/main/Queries/Sentinel%20Performance/Multiple-Playbook%20run%20failed.kql)

This is my workflow right now:
[image]
Query runs and outputs to a html table which gets emailed to me.

The issue is I know there are several logic apps in my environment that have **failing actions** or actions that are **disconnected**, that are not captured by my logic app + kql.

How would you tackle the problem of detecting and notifying when a logic app fails (both completely and when a particular action fails)

Comment: what are modules? Can you explain clearly what do you want to do

Comment: @RithwikBojja sorry the correct terminology is 'actions' not 'module'. I've edited the post to reflect that. I want to be notified when an action in any of my logic apps within a particular Resource group fails or the connection for a particular action disconnects (the ! icon appears)

Comment: The above logic app I made is an example solution however, it does not capture the failing actions of logic apps and often misses several logic app failures, particularly of those that are manually triggered and failed.

Comment: disconnection (the ! icon ) of a connection usually occurs when an account is logged into an action such as 'send an email' and then account is disabled. now the connection will break. or maybe there another connection to an action via an oauth app and the privileges change - then it is disconnected. I don't care how its disconnected. I just wanted to be alerted when it is.

Comment: @SPT the solution provided is not a realistic solution. The solution needs to be scalable to account for all logic apps (100s) across a resource group. Needs to address both connections that are broken and failures.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to get alerts on logic app **each action failure**, I have provided a way by trying with parallel action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are logic applications which are not appearing in your logs, make sure that you are sending their diagnostics settings to your Log Analytics workspace:

Go to `Logic apps > Monitoring - Diagnostics > Diagnostic Settings`:

[image: Logic app diagnostics settings location]

Ensure that you are forwarding settings to the correct Log Analytics workspace:
[image: Diagnostics Settings]

Then you should be able to query the logs using this basic KQL:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where OperationName endswith "workflowRunCompleted"
| summarize FailedRuns=countif(status_s == "Failed"), SuccessfulRuns=countif(status_s  == "Succeeded") by LogicApp=resource_workflowName_s, ResourceGroup=resource_resourceGroupName_s
| extend PercentageFailed = round(todouble(FailedRuns) / todouble(SuccessfulRuns)*100, 2)
```

You can adjust this as per your needs. Change line 2 to `| where OperationName contains "Microsoft.Logic/workflows` for all logic app events being collected.

Another reason the logic apps may not be appearing is if they have not been run in the Timeframe you are querying.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Logic Apps: How to be notified if a logic app act connection breaks or fails

One way is to check like below:

[image]

Another way is by adding parallel action after every action like below to get alerted:

[image]

If failed alert else if true then next action like below:

[image]

[image]

For the above steps to work you need to add in code like below:

**`runAfter to failed`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

So, like this for every action you need to add parallel action( i have done only for action parsejson for understanding of how to do) and for that action you need to change runafter to failed then you will get alert.

Also refer this [SO-Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75764961/17623802) and [SO-Thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75940004/not-getting-expected-error-message-from-nested-json-schema-validation/75945699#75945699)

Comment: This solution is not scalable. Imagine a real environment with 100s of logic apps each with a number of actions running. Do you see how the sample solution utilised azure diagnostic and sentinel health logs. To observe for failures across the environment. The above solution doesn't account for scaling into large environments

Comment: I want a single email or notification sent to me with all the failures and disconnected actions across the resource group in a given time period. The above solution would send multiple emails. The solution should be concise with its output like how Ive tabulated the results into a html table in the example solution

Comment: You can add an action append to array variable whenever there is a failure, parallelly for every action, at last send the mail if array length is more than 1 and i see no other way/option than this

Comment: There should be a way to look at the diagnostic logs of logic apps running, then query those logs. Such as azure diagnostic logs. It doesn't make sense to create additional actions for recording purposes. This is not scalable. I can't image any real environment that would ever do that. The solution to this problem lies in the logs collected rather than additional actions added to a logic app. You can see workflow triggers in Azure diagnostics, just need to find a way to extract that information better.

Answer (score 0):

the following KQL can show you the logic app, trigger from sentinel incident, action in logic app and event of that action.

```
AzureDiagnostics 
    | where OperationName contains "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"
    | extend OperationType = tostring(split(OperationName,'/')[2])
    | extend LogicApp = tostring(split(ResourceId,'/')[8])
    | extend IncidentNumber = toint(extract(@"[a-f0-9]{8}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-[a-f0-9]{4}\-[a-f0-9]{12}\_(\d+)", 1, correlation_clientTrackingId_s))
    | summarize Resource = strcat_array(make_set(Resource),', '),
     status_s = strcat_array(make_set(status_s),', ')  by LogicApp, IncidentNumber, OperationType, Level
```

This will output the exact information on logic app runs - however, im noticing not all logic apps appear here.