# Moving pdf files from Sharepoint to Blob Storage Container using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, power-automate, azure-logic-app-standard

I have created a flow where I am attempting to access the following path: "https://cactuscompany.sharepoint.com/sites/dataengineering". Within this path, there is a library named "Documents." Inside the "Documents" library, there are multiple folders like "Pfizer," "Roche," "AstraZeneca," etc. Each company folder contains both files and subfolders, and each subfolder has its own set of files.

My objective is to copy the PDF files from these folders and subfolders to a blob container. The files should be placed in the blob container without retaining the folder structure, only the files themselves...

[image]

However, the current flow only retrieves the list of folder names without including the files. what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The design you are using will only list the folder names or file names which are there directly without any folder then those files will be sent.

Below is how we can move all files.

The files in SharePoint:

[image]

Below is the **`design`** which works for me:

[image]

[image]

You should use **`Get Items`**  action. The disadvantage with get items is that you will also get folder name in an iteration.

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: yes, the workflow works well initially, but it abruptly stops after a minute or so. Even when I adjust the 'Action Timeout' in these actions, the issue persists. Any thoughts on why this might be happening? I have estimated that there are approximately 1500 to 3000 files in that location. it only copies around 98 files... The error I also get in the "Create Blob (V2)" is:

"The execution of template action 'Create_blob_(V2)' is skipped: the 'runAfter' condition for action 'Get_file_content_using_path' is not satisfied. Expected status values 'Succeeded' and actual value 'Failed'."

Comment: I already said that there is a limitation with this action that, if there are total 2 folders and subfolders and 10 files files, you will get 14 times iteration, this is because get items gives 14 paths so it also iterates with folder names. Beacus of that you will get 4 failed iterartions ad 10 passed. If you wnat run your workflow after failed also, you need to use runafter failed parameter in code of your logic app

Comment: Not sure why its abruptly stops, [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77270463/azure-logic-apps-how-to-be-notified-if-a-logic-app-action-connection-breaks-or/77271353#77271353)d where i used runafter. If it timeouts, I would suggest you to use Standard Logic app, which has more time dedicated for actions, Comsumption is used for less time actions.

Comment: Action timeout here is for the next retry to happen after how many minutes or hours, it doesn't increase time of action

Comment: All in all, would you say logic apps is the right tool for this requirement? Would data factory work better in this scenario?

Comment: Logic apps is useful only, not sure about adf though